# All views disappear when I select the apptheme .. android Studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, layout

put when I change the theme to (Holo Theme) it back again screen ..

apptheme:

[image]

holotheme:

[image]

Manifest:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit your `res/values/style.xml` e.g. :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme"/>
```

It is just an example. I think there's nothing behind your "AppTheme" right now.